# Dashing Graph X axis

Tags: python, dashing

I'm using Dashing and putting data into the graph widget using a python script running on a server accessing the API url.

It's working in that the graph displays the data python gets each minute as part of the cron job and a part of the graph displays but doesn't move.
I'm presuming this is because i'm not passing the last.point and only the current value.

Python:

```
data = '{ "auth_token":"YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "points": [{ "x":"1", "y":"9" }, {"x":"2","y": ' + str(status) + '}] }'
print(data)
url = 'http://10.0.0.40:3030/widgets/CB_stats'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
for x in f:
   print(x)
f.close()
```

This sends the value of (status) correctly.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Example graph]

This only ever shows the current value on the left side of the graph. It doesn't move.

The coffee script of the graph and rickshawgraph widgets haven't changed.
The X Axis part of the script is set to 'Time'.

Anyone know how i can start plotting the last, say 10 values and get the graph working?

Any help appreciated as i'm new to this using Python.

Comment: Try feeding X as epoch.

Comment: Why are you pushing Data to Dashing from Python? The intention of Dashing is that is pulls data in the Ruby backend. The API is more for 'push-only' applications, like user input.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input and you're right, i should be using Ruby to pull rather than push from Python. I was just struggling with the Ruby syntax.

I had someone who knows Ruby well look at the code and we managed to fix it.
Below is how this was done if anyone comes across this in the future.

```
# jobs/CB_Ops_job.rb
require './lib/dashing_ec2'
require "aws-sdk"
require "active_support/all"

cw = Aws::CloudWatch::Client.new({
    :access_key_id => "ACCESS-KEY",
    :secret_access_key => "SECRET-ACCESS-KEY",
    :region => 'eu-west-1'
})

SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  series = []
      resp = cw.get_metric_statistics(
        namespace: '<Your NameSpace>',
        metric_name: '<YourMetric>',
     dimensions: [
        {name: "InstanceId", value: "i-XXXXXXX"}
    ],
    start_time: 15.minute.ago,
    end_time: Time.now,
    period: 60,
    statistics: ["Average"]
      )

  puts resp.label

  value = 0.0
  resp.datapoints.sort do |x, y|
    x.timestamp <=> y.timestamp
  end.each_with_index do |x, index|
    series.push({x: index, y: x.average})
    puts x.timestamp
    value = x.average
  end

  data = { points: series, max: 2000, status: 'ok' }
  data[:status] = 'warning' if value > 3000
  data[:status] = 'danger' if value > 1000 && value < 3000

  puts data

  send_event "CB_Ops", data
end
```